# CSS ">" selector not working, neither is "~"

Tags: html, css

I have got the following CSS:

```
.images_container input[type="checkbox"]:checked > label { border-color:#4378c3; opacity:1.0; }
.images_container input[type="checkbox"] > label:hover { opacity:1.0; }
.images_container input[type="checkbox"] { display:block; }
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div class="sale_image_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$result_id?>_checkbox" value="<?=$result_id?>" name="product[]" />
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;" />
        <label style="background-image:url(<?=$img?>)" class="sale_image" for="<?=$result_id?>_checkbox">
            <div class="jpg_name_bg">
                <div class="jpg"><?=$result_jpg?></div>
                <img src="images/expand.png" onClick="expandImage('<?=$img?>')" />
                <img src="images/fx.png" onClick="applyEffects('<?=$result_jpg?>')" />
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the first two styles are not working at all... when the checkbox is checked, the label should have that style applied to it...

Comment: `>` is the immediate descendant selector, and an `input` can't have descendants.

Comment: In your CSS you have `.image_container`, but your HTML has `sale_image_container`.

Comment: This `.images_container input[type="checkbox"] > label:hover` matches nothing as there is no (and can be no) `label` inside of an `input`. Also as @RocketHazmat pointed out, in the markup provided there is no class `image_container`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input[type="checkbox"] > label:hover` means `label` which is a direct child of `input` with `type=checkbox`. That's not what your HTML looks like. And it's not possible at all, because `input` cannot have any children.

You can try using `+` to get `div` right next to `input` and then `>` to get the `label`:

```
.images_container input[type="checkbox"] + div > label:hover { opacity:1.0; }
```

Comment: He also has the class `sale_image` on `label` so he can get it using `label.sale_image { ... }`

Comment: Code got a bit messy as it did work before somehow and then I broke it. I see what your saying now and got it working with your example, thanks!